# Git rebase --merge with only some of the commits

Tags: git

I did a few commits, say commit A, B, C
Now I want to push only commit A and B to the remote repo. (And keep commit C to be merged and pushed at a later time)
Before I push, I need to run:

```
git fetch origin master
git rebase --merge FETCH_HEAD
```

problem is the above commands will ask me to resolve conflicts of commit C as well, which I'm not planning to push now.

Is it possible to do the rebase without having to deal with commit C.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Saving before the rebase

The easiest way to save the commit so you can postpone dealing with the conflicts would be to tag it so you have a reference to the commit later:

```
$ git tag save-commitC <sha1>
```

#### Rebasing without commit C

After you've saved a reference, rebase without the commit:

```
$ git rebase --interactive --merge FETCH_HEAD
```

It should open your editor to file looking like this:

```
pick <sha1> <message>
pick <sha1> <message>
pick <sha1> <message>
...
```

To **delete** commit C from this branch's history, simply remove or comment out the commit's `pick <sha1> <message>` line.

Note that commits are listed in reverse order, with the oldest commits *first*, the most recent ones *last*.  The first commit on the list should be the first commit that is not an ancestor of `FETCH_HEAD`.

Once you've rebased without C, go ahead and push:

```
$ git push origin master
```

#### Reapplying the commit

When you're ready to apply it on the rebased branch:

```
$ git cherry-pick save-commitC
   # resolve merge conflicts
$ git commit
$ git tag -d save-commitC
```

Comment: this won't permanently delete the commit, right? I mean, I'll still be able to apply it later?

Comment: This will, actually. :/  I'll update the answer with a way to keep track of it if you do want to keep it.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of warning. -_-  It wouldn't have been completely lost, but it would have been a lot more annoying to track down.

Comment: Thanks, what will change if I have A,B,C,D (instead of A,B,C), and I want to merge only A,B? Is it ok to use: git tag save-commitCD <sha1> <sha2> ?

Comment: The simple way is to run `git tag save-commitX <sha1>` for each commit you want to save (you can't create multiple tags at once), but later you *can* cherry-pick them all at once: `git cherry-pick save-commitC save-commitD`.

The other way is to just make a tag on the last commit you made (`D`), and then later you can do `git cherry-pick save-commitD~1 save-commitD` to pick `D` and its parent.

Comment: great thanks. last question (hopefully): is there a side-effect for creating tags? Are they just temporary names or they will appear in the remote repo somehow? I'm trying to understand the difference between your solution and @limscoder's solution. I understand that yours is more generic, but they both look ok for my case. What do you think?

Comment: Tags are usually used as long-term markers for specific commits (like release versions of code).  As long as you specify that you're pushing `master`, they won't push to the remote server (you probably should delete them once you're done, though, or you may accidentally push them eventually).  The main difference is that stashing saves the *working tree*, not commit objects, so it would only work for one commit at a time.  Which is fine for this case, so his probably is the better solution. (eyeroll)

Comment: Actually, I have more than 1 commit that I want to delay (i.e. C is a group of commits). I think I'll use your method, as it looks more explicit and flexible.

Comment: If it's one contiguous group of commits, I would highly recommend just tagging the last (most recent) one.  Then you can specify a range behind it to cherry-pick them all.

Comment: how do I specify a range? And, haven't we said that if I don't save a commit it will get lost? Does tagging the last commit prevent losing the previous ones?

Comment: Ex. `git cherry-pick tag~3..tag` would pick `tag` and three commits before it. Every commit contains a reference to its parent, so a reference to the last commit is a reference to its parents.  This is why branch names are literally nothing more than references to the last commit on that branch.

Answer (score 2):

You could reset to commit b, then stash your changes, push, and then reapply your stash.

```
git reset HEAD~1
git stash
(rebasing or whatever other intermediate steps required go here)
git push
git stash pop
```

Comment: This assumes commit's A,B,C are in order and the last 3 commits.

Comment: Actually this assumption is ok in my case. I've already reordered my commits so they are in order and they are the last commits.