# How to copy one branch to another in git

Tags: git

I need to copy one branch to another in git. I need to copy only the commits from **fix** branch to **master**, only the last three commits. How can I do that?

```
- x - x - x (master)
  \
   x - x (dev)
        \
         x - x - x (fix)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git rebase --merge with only some of the commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250437/git-rebase-merge-with-only-some-of-the-commits)

Comment: The branch `fix` includes all the commits going back to the initial commit, and so overlaps with `dev` and `master`. What you want is only the commits in `fix` but *not* in `dev`.

Comment: That is, branches are defined solely by their *head*, not by a common ancestor shared with any particular branch.

Comment: @voiarn I even saw this post before posting mine but I wasn't sure how to apply it to my situation as I'm not that fluent in rebase

Answer (score 2):

You could say

```
git switch master
git cherry-pick dev..fix
```

Or you could do the same thing by saying

```
git switch fix
git switch -c temp
git rebase --onto master dev temp
git switch master
git reset --hard temp
git branch -D temp
```

Either way, now `master` has acquired three new commits which are copies of the three commits on `fix` after `dev`.

Comment: cherry-pick range of commits works pretty cool, thanks

Comment: They are actually the same. Rebase is cherry pick.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new branch from master(say, hotfix-abcd), and cherry-pick the commits in `fix`.

Lets say you have these three commits in `fix`,

```
a1234 FixBob
a1235 FixAlice
a1232 FixTom
```

1. Go to master, `git checkout master`
2. Create a branch from the head, `git checkout -b 'hotfix-abcd'`
3. Now you'll be in `hotfix-abcd` branch, cherry-pick the commits `git cherry-pick a1234 a1235 a1232`
4. Create a Pull Request from `hotfix-abcd` to `master`.